# CSS formatting of AJAX json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using jquery to make a call to a hardcoded json file. Each json object has name, image, and description.

I need to make the page display each json as a listed item as displayed in the below mockup image.

page mockup

[image]

Here is my script file:

```
$(function() {
$.ajax(
{
  url: 'javascripts/avocado.json',
  data: {}
}).done(function(response) {
console.log(response);
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
  $('#avocado-list').append('<div class="avocado-item"></div>')
  $('.avocado-item').append('<h2>' + (i + 1) + '</h2>');
  $('.avocado-item h2').addClass("avocado-number");
  $('.avocado-item').append('<img src="../images/' + response[i].img + '">');
  $('.avocado-item').append('<div><h3>' + response[i].name + '</h3>' + '<p>' + response[i].description + '</p></div>');
  $('.avocado-item h3').addClass("avocado-title");
}
}).fail(function() {
console.log("error");
}).always(function() {
console.log("complete");
});
});
```

and the HTML where I am trying to load the json data:

```
<section id="avocado-list" class="list"></section>
```

I am trying to create a div of avocado-item for each json object. Then I am trying to append its subsequent data (name, image, description) into the div so that I can the objects information together in one line.

However it is only creating one big div for everything. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating HTML the way you have done is very inefficient. This is a more simple version of your code that should do what you are after.

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'javascripts/avocado.json',
    data: {}
  }).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var listMarkup = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
      listMarkup += '<div class="avocado-item"><h2 class="avocado-number">' + (i + 1) + '</h2><img src="../images/' + response[i].img + '"><div><h3 class="avocado-title">' + response[i].name + '</h3>' + '<p>' + response[i].description + '</p></div></div>';
    }

    $('#avocado-list').append(listMarkup);
  }).fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
  }).always(function() {
    console.log("complete");
  });
});
```

Comment: @AndrewChan If this reply answered your question. You should click the gray tick at the left-hand side to mark it accepted.